# Having trouble getting the value of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to look into the value of input and weights tensors in the training process in my layer, I have used the code from keras tutorial [here](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/) on writing a training loop, and used a dropout layer definition that I found in another thread in order to get the mask, which is kind of hacky but not the main problem here:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops

class MyDR(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,rate,parentLayer,**kwargs):
        super(MyDR, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.parentLayer = parentLayer
        self.noise_shape = None
        self.rate = rate


    def _get_noise_shape(self,x, noise_shape=None):
        # If noise_shape is none return immediately.
        if noise_shape is None:
            return array_ops.shape(x)
        try:
            # Best effort to figure out the intended shape.
            # If not possible, let the op to handle it.
            # In eager mode exception will show up.
            noise_shape_ = tensor_shape.as_shape(noise_shape)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return noise_shape

        if x.shape.dims is not None and len(x.shape.dims) == len(noise_shape_.dims):
            new_dims = []
            for i, dim in enumerate(x.shape.dims):
                if noise_shape_.dims[i].value is None and dim.value is not None:
                    new_dims.append(dim.value)
                else:
                    new_dims.append(noise_shape_.dims[i].value)
            return tensor_shape.TensorShape(new_dims)

        return noise_shape

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.noise_shape = input_shape
        print(self.noise_shape)
        super(MyDR,self).build(input_shape)

    @tf.function
    def call(self,input):
        self.noise_shape = self._get_noise_shape(input)
        random_tensor = tf.random.uniform(self.noise_shape, seed=1235, dtype=input.dtype)
        keep_prob = 1 - self.rate
        scale = 1 / keep_prob
        # NOTE: if (1.0 + rate) - 1 is equal to rate, then we want to consider that
        # float to be selected, hence we use a >= comparison.
        self.keep_mask = random_tensor >= self.rate
        #pdb.set_trace()
        #NOTE: here is where I save the binary masks. 
        #the file grows quite big!
        #tf.print(self.keep_mask,output_stream="file://temp/droput_mask.txt")

        ret = input * scale * math_ops.cast(self.keep_mask, input.dtype)
        return ret
```

here is how I instantiate my model:

```
dropout = 0.05

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(1,))
newl = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="layer1")
inter = newl(inputs)
inter = MyDR(dropout,parentLayer=newl)(inter)
newl = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="layer2")
inter = newl(inter)
inter = MyDR(dropout,parentLayer=newl)(inter)
newl = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="layer3")
inter = newl(inter)
inter = MyDR(dropout,parentLayer=newl)(inter)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, name="layer4")(inter)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

I try it out on a simple regression problem, and it works fine, but I would like to check the value of tensors during training, which is why I used a pdb.set_trace() (so that the debugger will stop in the call and I can check my mask and input value) in the call to my dropout layer, but I get an error if I try:

```
ipdb> input
<tf.Tensor 'input:0' shape=(20, 100) dtype=float32>
ipdb> keras.backend.eval(input)
*** AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy'
```

I've read that it can come from eager execution not being enable, but since I am using tf 2.0 it is enabled by default
I don't understand why it is so hard just to get the values... If anyone has a way to get it that would save my day.

Comment: Because layer Input is not something that holds value, it just a spec layer.

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by spec layer?

Comment: The `keras.Input` - it's a specification layer, which means it doesn't hold any value to return. You can only get the `shape` of it.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, `tf.keras.Input` is just a specification layer that holds the shape information of the upcoming tensor. So if you want to get the output value of this layer, you need to pass some tensor. For example:

```
model.layers[0](tf.ones(1,1)).numpy() 
array([1.], dtype=float32)

tf.keras.backend.eval(model.layers[0](tf.ones(1,1)))
array([1.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but isnt that what is already happening in the training loop? In the keras tutorial we are using a tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices to get x_batch_training and pass it to the model, doesn't it contain values?

Comment: That's true. But look, you just build the model `model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)`, all of the internal layers contain only the shape of the upcoming tensor (e.g. tf.data.).

Comment: I see, the model first get initialized with only the input shape, however when i start the training , it stops only one time with still only the shapes, and then never stops again in the call method. Isn't it supposed to pass in the call function each step of the training?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your point. What do you mean it stops one time and never stops...?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean on the debugger pdb.set_trace() commented in the layer call method

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use pdb inside the call method. For debugging `keras` layers/model, see this. https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/debugging_tips/